# material - single faces - Blender Game Rendering

Tags: materials

I am working on my first blender project
- I learnd before that Cycles Render will be the Render Engine of the future
- So I set up objects with materials (using material and texture Nodes) with cycles.
Than I wanted to use BGE logic bricks to let a person run through the rooms.

When I changed to Blender Game Rendering engine, I had to allpy the materials again. but I cannot apply different materials on single faces of my person - object: so I have following questions:
- how can I apply different materials for single faces?
- how can I use material nodes in "Blender Game" render engine
- Is cycles "Cycles Render" only for rendering high quality pictures and videos?
...
I tryied to attache screenshots to my question showing the situation in Cycles Render and then in Blender Game. But I could not find the option to do this.
Any help will be appreciated!!!!
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you intend to use the BGE, then you have to select it from the render engines, in which case blender internal and cycles wont work, Yet you can assign different materials in the bge for different faces of your madel, just add a material slot and make a new mat, enter edit mode, select faces, and click "assign" in the material settings.

Comment: You can use cycles rendering to create textures, then bake texture to images and apply those textures to BGE materials

Comment: how to attach screenshots (videos are not supported, only animated gif): https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Thanks for your answers however 
- To Yvains anser: this is exactly what I tried, but when I was applying a new material on the selected face in edit mode all the object did get the material - maybe I did something wrong - I will try again.

Comment: my reply to m.ardito: 
I want to try this in the future: but I am not yet so far....